# Clean up entryway into garage

Tags: carpentry

I'm looking to clean up the entry way to my garage. I've built a box to house some wires and I'd like the entry to the garage to extend over it and down onto a step I built also. The box is the light colored wood here and lacks a top and the gap is about 2 in.

How would I create a good top for the wiring box, and extend the door threshold to make it seamless? Could /should I extend the entire door frame out a little?

[image: entryway]

[image: Second angle]

Comment: How much open free space do you have?  Before stuff gets in the way.  You probably want a landing type, but the height requires a step which will stick out.  Does anything(car, car door)  go over that mat?

Comment: Most of the doorframe just needs trim on this side, which it's utterly lacking. Do that after drywall where the drywall is missing at present.

Comment: The step is as far as I can go as to not impede a car from being pulled into the garage. not pictured is the top of the wooden box above the step where there’s a 2 inch gap of space right now.

Comment: @crip659 - updated the post with a new photo

Comment: I am assuming the wires are near the bottom.  Spacers(1x4,2x4) between the door frame and new wood so everything can be nailed/screwed together on the top section to make those 1x4s stiff.

Comment: They are encased in the top level! @crip659 - the bottom part is a fat sill the bottom 1x3 is screwed to

Comment: Even if the wires are not at the bottom, should still be space to stuff in a 1x2 or 2x2 at the top.  You just want something to fill the top in and to screw those boards tight to the door frame/bottom.  Picture might not be showing enough, but those boards seem like they are just loose at the door way, nothing making them solid to the door.

Comment: yes, they’re not secured because it’s a box structure made specifically to enclose the wires. but I think I see what you’re saying. Thank you.